# AngularFire used to have a orderByPriority filter

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

From Google result it looks like AngularFire used to have a orderByPriority filter. But I cannot find this in the current AngularFire api docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html. As I understand it, orderByPriority converted an objects properties into to an array. I guess this filter is gone because there is another and better way to do it now, but what is that method?

Comment: Something like `$firebase(new Firebase('https://yours.firebaseio.com/path/to/items').orderByPriority()).$asArray()` should work. If it's giving you problems (I didn't try this, so it may not copy/paste/work), update your question to show your relevant snippet.

Comment: The `orderByPriority` method of AngularFire was removed in release 0.8.0. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/changelog.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer a need for `orderByPriority` since you can utilize a synchronized array, which is already implicitly ordered.

So in ancient days, you would do something like:

```
$scope.data = $firebase(ref);

<div ng-repeat="item in data | orderByPriority" />
```

In not so ancient times (i.e. 0.8.x or greater) you would simply choose an array format:

```
$scope.data = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

<div ng-repeat="item in data" />
```

Comment: Old - use $firebaseObject and $firebaseArray instead. Doesn't seem to be a solution for a simple -created_at reverse order. . . weird how the simplest things are not supported by firebase . . .

Comment: This was written before field level queries existed. Created at reverse order is this simple:  `recordRef.child('created_at').set( - date );` `recordRef.orderByChild('created_at').on(...)`