# How to filter returned Firebase Items as an array if you cannot use orderByPriority?

Tags: arrays, filter, firebase

After googling lots of threads on this topic it seems Firebase cannot store data as arrays: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html

which is a real pain when it comes to filtering. I am creating a simple global search service:

```
 servicesModule.factory('globalFilter', function() {
    return {
      searchText: []
    };
  });
```

with your typical sitewide search box:

```
        <form>
              <div class="input-field">
                <input id="search" type="search" required ng-model="globalFilter.searchText">
                <label for="search"><i class="material-icons medium">search</i></label>
              </div>
        </form>
```

Which will filter the results based on the current view so if you are in home you will have a view with an ng-repeat directive:

```
<div class="col s12 m6"  id="postItems" ng-repeat="article in articles | filter: globalFilter.search">
```

However it throws the same error: `Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received:` and I cannot use firebaseArray in the case of globalFilter.searchText because the value is empty. I have tried to add its empty value in empty '`[]`' but it still does not get picked up as an array.

Surely other people must have had similar problems with this, and if so how to create a "Firebase/Angular-friendly" search filter?

UPDATE: I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150562/a-orderby-object-filter-for-pure-firebase-js-api)

But it will still not work for me and I believe it is because articles is a firebasearray and not object. so I get the following error:
`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: orderByPriorityFilterProvider`T

CONTROLLER FOR ARTICLES

```
controllersModule.controller('BlogCtrl', ["$scope", "dataService", "globalFilter", function($scope, dataService, globalFilter) {



        dataService.query(function(articles){
             $scope.myArticles = articles;
         })
}]);
```

**The Firebase query service:**

```
servicesModule.factory("dataService", function($resource){
    return $resource("https://<SOURCE>.firebaseio.com/articles.json", {
        id: "@id"
     },
     {
         update: {
             method: "PUT"
         },
         query: {
           method: 'GET'}
    });
});
```

JSON FORMAT

**Articles.json**

```
article {
1: {
  Title: "Are you suggesting that coconuts migrate?",
  Body: "<p>Go and boil your bottoms, sons of a silly person! I blow my nose at you, so-called Ah-thoor Keeng, you and all your silly English K-n-n-n-n-n-n-n-niggits! She looks like one.</p><p>Where'd you get the coconuts? The swallow may fly south with the sun, and the house martin or the plover may seek warmer climes in winter, yet these are not strangers to our land. It's only a model. But you are dressed as one…</p>",
  Intro: "You don't frighten us, English pig-dogs!",
  Tags: [{text: "coconuts"},{text: "migraine"},{text: "headaches"}]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your controller's code. Specifically, where the `articles` variable is instantiated.

Comment: I'm not an Angular expert, but this `filter: global.search` also looks different from `servicesModule.factory('globalFilter'`. Please set up a minimal, complete, verifiably example. A jsfiddle/jsbin is usually the easiest way for us to see what you're doing.

Comment: Please see above. I cannot set a fiddle on time as I have too many dependencies but will try when I have a moment. But I am using the service as query, I need to iterate through it depending on the section. I initially thought it would be simple by adding an Angular filter but it only takes arrays and I cannot find a way to filter via Firebasearray or convert it with Angular.

Comment: Can't build a fiddle unfortunately, too many dependencies, I cannot share the source url. Ben looking everywhere, there does not seem to be an easy way to use Angular filter with Firebase, unless you convert the source into a basic Firebase object which destroys the whole purpose of using resource and Firebase array.

Comment: It looks like you're using the REST API and not $firebaseArray. To order by priority, [you need to request the priority be included and then sort it on the client-side](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-param-format). This code really has little to do with Firebase, since the API just returns JSON. Is your data indexed in such a way that you would get an array back?

Comment: Thanks Anid. Bu I am still having all kinds of problems. First adding `orderByPriority | ` to the Angular filter results in `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: orderByPriorityFilterProvider <- orderByPriorityFilter`. So I removed it. And to my dataService Rest API I appended `"https://datasource.firebaseio.com/Posts.json?orderBy=\'$priority\'"` which resulted in `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)` Even if it loads on the browser (unescaped). I am running out of ideas.

Comment: I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117581/angularfire-used-to-have-a-orderbypriority-filter So it looks like orderByPriority no longer exists. People really need to make up their minds on Firebase and Angular about what to keep and what to ditch. Impossible to keep up.

Comment: My recommendation is that you use AngularFire instead of trying to reinvent the wheel. `$scope.articles = $firebaseArray(new Firebase("https://datasource.firebaseio.com/articles"))` addresses all of your issues. It's already sorted and is an array that can be filtered.

Comment: But how can this become a resource across multiple controllers?

Comment: Just call $firebaseArray wherever you need it. The Firebase sdk handles caching. Or return it from a factory the same way you'd share data in any other circumstance. [Check out their docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/) and post a new question if you need help with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92182/discussion-between-hgb-and-anid-monsur).

Comment: I made an attempt at what you suggested at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111096/using-firebasearray-instead-of-firebase-rest-api . Now I am getting no errors, but no results either. Nothing happens.