# Using $firebaseArray instead of Firebase Rest API

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter, firebase

Hi I am having problems filtering search results from a Firebase datasource as a result of Firebase's lack of support for array storage so I am using firebaseArray as an alternative. However as it needs to be accessed via multiple controllers I have to turn it into a factory service:

```
servicesModule.factory("dataArray", ["$firebaseArray",
  function($firebaseArray) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://datasource.firebaseio.com/Articles");
     return $firebaseArray(ref);
  }
]);
```

I then want to create a search function to filter the results of an input form query:

```
//Get Posts
 servicesModule.factory('globalFilter', function() {
    return {
      searchText: ''
    };
  });
```

The Search Input:

```
<form>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input id="search" type="search" required ng-model="globalFilter.searchText">
            <label for="search"><i class="material-icons medium">search</i></label>
          </div>
    </form>
```

**Here is an example controller accessing the filter and array factories:**

```
   controllersModule.controller('BlogCtrl', ["$scope",  "globalFilter",    function($scope, globalFilter, dataArray) {


     $scope.myArticles = dataArray;


   }]);
```

**The filter inside the ng-repeat directive for the controller:**

```
<div class="col s12 m6"  id="articleItems" ng-repeat="article in myarticles">
     <div class="card small">

       <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
         <img class="activator" src="images/sample-1.jpg">
       </div>
       <div class="card-content">
         <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">{{article.Title}}<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
         <p><a href="#">Read More</a></p>
         <p>By: {{article.Author}} &nbsp; Published on: {{article.Published | date:'mediumDate'}}</p>
       </div>
       <div class="card-reveal">
         <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">{{article.Title}}<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
         <div>{{article.Intro}}</div>
         <p ng-bind-html="article.Body">{{article.Body}}</p>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Controller rendered via `.state`

The controller is also rendered via `.state`:`

```
  .state('Blog', {

   url: '/blog',
    controller: 'BlogCtrl as blg',
    templateUrl: 'blog.html',
    title: 'Blog'
  })`
```

I am getting no errors or results. The console is blank and the articles do not render. This was working before I used firebaseArray. What is wrong with my factory?

Comment: Can you post the HTML where you're using ng-repeat?

Comment: For some reason the post did not render it. I just adjusted the spacing above and you can see it.

Comment: The controller is also rendered via `.state` so: `  .state('Blog', {
    url: '/blog',
    controller: 'BlogCtrl as blg',
    templateUrl: 'blog.html',
    title: 'Blog'
  })`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `controllerAs`, you need to bind your controller variables to `this`.

```
controllersModule.controller('BlogCtrl', ["globalFilter", function(globalFilter, dataArray) {
    this.myArticles = dataArray;
}]);
```

You also need to refer to your controller as `blg` in your view. Lastly, `myarticles` should be `myArticles`.

```
<div class="col s12 m6"  id="articleItems" ng-repeat="article in blg.myArticles">
```

Comment: All good comments, thanks but still failing silently. It is strange because in my view I have {{blg.title}} as an <h2> heading and that is rendering fine from the controller set "this.title = " My Blog Title" value,  but not the data source. Also if I put it back to `dataSource.query(function(posts){$scope.myPosts = posts;})` i.e. using the API it works fine even using $scope. This is why I think that there is something wrong with the firebaseArray service.

Comment: What about security rules?

Comment: There shouldn't be as I have other controllers using the firebaseArray (not as a service mind) example: controllersModule.controller('WelcomeCtrl', ["$scope", '$location', 'CommonProp', "$firebaseAuth",  '$firebaseObject','$firebaseArray',
  function($scope, $location, CommonProp, $firebaseAuth,  $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {
    var ref = new Firebase('https://datasource.firebaseio.com/Posts');
    var myPosts = $firebaseArray(ref);
    $scope.myPosts = myPosts;

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't work. Can't diagnose it without seeing more of your code. Works fine in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OsKaQU6kZf2MqrMSvGsJ?p=preview

Comment: I need to take a look at your code more carefully when it is not the middle of the night. But what I notice first is that you put the search input inside the view controller. Does it have to be in order to work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. As long as the ng-model of the input is available to the scope the ng-repeat is in, it will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92202/discussion-between-hgb-and-anid-monsur).

Comment: I was prompted to create a chat room for this topic by stackoverflow, are you able to see my reply?